# What do hits on bosses in Donkey Kong Country Returns mean and how do I earn them?

Tags: nintendo-wii, donkey-kong-country-returns

In *Donkey Kong Country Returns* for the Nintendo Wii, after beating a boss it always tells me I got "1 Hit". It's clear to me that I am supposed to do something to get more hits, presumably during the animation of Donkey Kong punching the boss. However nothing I have done increases the number of hits. I have shaken the wiimote, pressed buttons, etc.

What are these "hits"? How do you get more hits after beating a boss? What are they good for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get multiple hits on a boss, **there is a small time span just before Donkey Kong punches the boss and just after where you need to start shaking the controller** like you would when doing a ground pound.  It takes some practice to figure out the right moment to start.  If you shake too early or late, you won't get any additional hits.

The most hits I've gotten was 23.  I've never earned anything for the hits, so **I don't think they're good for anything more than bragging rights**.

Comment: Nope nothing other than bragging rights (here I thought 14 was high).

Comment: I read in an interview somewhere that it's just to let the player vent frustration

Comment: update: it was in this interview: http://us.wii.com/iwata_asks/donkey-kong-country-returns/vol1_page1.jsp

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to get 23 hits on a boss. I thought I had determined to a certainty that the maximum number of hits on a boss was 20, and on an end-of-level barrel was 15.